# jQuery - Can I mix mulitple JS code that processes different forms into on JS

Tags: jquery

I have designed several web forms each of which links to a single form_operation.js.
This JS file handles all kinds different interaction on different forms.

It works so far for me. My question is: Are there some potential problems I will have in the future?

For example,
Assuem I have two forms a) login.php b) register.php.

Each form has defined different DIVs with different IDs. When login.php loads the form_operation.js, it can see some DIVs that are defined in register.php.

Most code is embedded into

```
/////////////// form_operation.js  ////////////////////
function fun1() {}
function fun2() {}
$(document).ready(function() { // handle form 1.. } );
$(document).ready(function() { // handle form 1 & 2.. } );
$(document).ready(function() { // handle form 1 } );
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the code **isn't interdependent** (e.g. one `document.ready` handler doesn't dely on another to be executed first) then you're ok mixing and matching event handlers as needed.

If you posted your markup I could give a bit more advice here, but from what you have,  there's not immediately anything wrong.  As a general rule, combine what you can where it makes sense and it's more maintainable to do so, but the cost of rigging up multiple `document.ready` handlers is *very* low...so use as many as makes sense for your application.  Just make sure they don't depend on each other, if they *do* you should explicitly call them in the order they need to run.